# Proving `weaken` doesn't change the value of a number

Tags: idris

Let's say we want to prove that weakening the upper bound of a `Data.Fin` doesn't change the value of the number. The intuitive way to state this is:

```
weakenEq : (num : Fin n) -> num = weaken num
```

Let's now generate the defini... Hold on! Let's think a bit about that statement. `num` and `weaken num` have different *types*. Can we state the equality in this case?

The documentation on `=` suggests we can try to, but we might want to use `~=~` instead. Well, anyway, let's go ahead and generate the definition and case-split, resulting in

```
weakenEq : (num : Fin n) -> num = weaken num
weakenEq FZ = ?weakenEq_rhs_1
weakenEq (FS x) = ?weakenEq_rhs_2
```

The goal in the `weakenEq_rhs_1` hole is `FZ = FZ`, which still makes sense from the value point of view. So we optimistically replace the hole with `Refl`, but only to fail:

```
When checking right hand side of weakenEq with expected type
        FZ = weaken FZ

Unifying k and S k would lead to infinite value
```

A somewhat cryptic error message, so we wonder if that's really related to the types being different.

Anyway, let's try again, but now with `~=~` instead of `=`. Unfortunately, the error is still the same.

So, how one would state and prove that `weaken x` doesn't change the value of `x`? Does it really make sense to? What should I do if that's a part of a larger proof where I might want to `rewrite` a `Vect n (Fin k)` with `Vect n (Fin (S k))` that's obtained by `map`ping `weaken` over the original vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to prove that the value of the `Fin n` does not change after applying the weaken function, you would need to prove the equality of these values:

```
weakenEq: (num: Fin n) -> finToNat num = finToNat $ weaken num
weakenEq FZ     = Refl
weakenEq (FS x) = cong $ weakenEq x
```

Comment: As for your second problem - I did not manage to solve that:

    vectorWeakenEq: (v: Vect n (Fin k)) -> map (Data.Fin.finToNat) v = map (Data.Fin.finToNat . Data.Fin.weaken) v
    vectorWeakenEq [] = Refl
    vectorWeakenEq (x :: xs) = let hypo = vectorWeakenEq xs in ?hole

Answer (score 1):

To your second problem/Markus' comment about `map (Data.Fin.finToNat) v = map (Data.Fin.finToNat . Data.Fin.weaken) v`:

```
vectorWeakenEq : (v: Vect n (Fin k)) -> 
                 map Fin.finToNat v = map (Fin.finToNat . Fin.weaken) v
vectorWeakenEq [] = Refl
vectorWeakenEq (x :: xs) =
  rewrite sym $ weakenEq x in
  cong {f=(::) (finToNat x)} (vectorWeakenEq xs)
```

And to see why `num = weaken num` won't work, let's take a look at a counterexample:

```
getSize : Fin n -> Nat
getSize _ {n} = n
```

Now with `x : Fin n`, `getSize x = n != (n + 1) = getSize (weaken x)`. This won't happen with functions which only depend on the constructors, like `finToNat`. So you have to constrain yourself to those and prove that they behave like that.

Comment: That's indeed a very interesting counterexample, thought-provoking on the semantics of `=` and the effects of `rewrite`!